# Why is js parseInt not working for this particular integer?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

Here is my string: "6145390195186705543"

I have tried parseInt with different radix values. I have tried the Number() method. And I have tried multiplying it by one. They all give back 6145390195186705000

Why is this??

Comment: the number is already exceeded the upper limit of integer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin